# Inner foreach loop not continuing from second element on second iteration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have used a break inside inner foreach loop and continued the outer loop but when it comes to inner foreach again it started from first item not the second one. Need your help.

```cs
foreach (var item in list1)
{
    bool flag = false;
    foreach (var item in list2)
    {
        item.category = item.category;
        item.text = item.text;
        item.key = item.key;

        db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        flag = true;
        break;
    }
    if(flag) continue;
}
```

Comment: The primary issue here is that your two loops share the same `item` variable name. **Don't do that**. Use `itemOuter` and `itemInner`.

Comment: How about you started telling us what the goal is? Right now you have two variables with the same names, used in both the inner and outer scope of each loop.

Comment: The exact reason for the downvote, _IS_ the fact that we dont understand your question.

Comment: yeah actually i shared just an example here ,not the actual one .So i just wanted to know if it is possible to start the inner loop again from the second item ?@mjwills

Comment: And a goal description for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use same index from both collection, use code like below

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
{
    item item1 = list1[i];
    item item2 = list2[i];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is exactly what should happen if you break out of a `foreach`loop and the hit it again.
If you want to continue at the second or third or nth position just don't break out of the loop, either use `continue;`. Let me give you an example:

```cs
// This is a List of Lists of ints we'll iterate over
var outerList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var innerList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

foreach(var outerItem in outerList)
{
    // This will print '1, 2, 3, 4, 5' over the course of execution (as expected)
    Console.WriteLine($"outerList item: {outerItem}");
    foreach (var innerItem in innerList)
    {
        // This will always print '1', never something else (as expected)*
        Console.WriteLine($"innerList item: {innerItem}");
        break;
    }
}
```

* This is because the `foreach` can never continue to the second entry of the `innerList`, so it just prints the first entry 5 (or however many items are in the `outerList`) times. The entire output will look like so (without the # ...)

```
outerList item: 1
innerList item: 1
outerList item: 2
innerList item: 1
outerList item: 3
innerList item: 1
outerList item: 4
innerList item: 1
outerList item: 5
innerList item: 1
```

Now if we remove the `break` this will be the output:

```
outerList item: 1
innerList item: 1
innerList item: 2
innerList item: 3
innerList item: 4
innerList item: 5
outerList item: 2
innerList item: 1
...
```

If at the second iteration of the outer loop you want to start at the second position in the inner loop, you'd need to use a standard `for` loop and an integer iterator, something like so:

```cs
var outerList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
var innerList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

for (int i = 0; i < outerList.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"outerList item: {outerList[i]}");
    for (int j = i; j < innerList.Count; j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"innerList item: {innerList[j]}");
    }
}
```

This will as expected print:

```
outerList item: 1
innerList item: 1
innerList item: 2
innerList item: 3
innerList item: 4
innerList item: 5
outerList item: 2
innerList item: 2
innerList item: 3
innerList item: 4
innerList item: 5
outerList item: 3
innerList item: 3
innerList item: 4
innerList item: 5
outerList item: 4
innerList item: 4
innerList item: 5
outerList item: 5
innerList item: 5
```

p.s Notice how I used separate names for the outer/ inner List and also for the iterators. Else this wouldn't even compile (@mjwills already pointed this out in the comments)

Comment: The same idea helped me .Thanks a lot you are little bit late but you explained much better thanks @MindSwipe

Comment: Nice idea using different variable names for the inner and outer variables.